# How to know annotation index MKMapview ios

Tags: objective-c, iphone, methods, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

Hi i have 100 annotations in mapview ontap of one of its annotations i should get **annotation index** related to that.
Does anyone have idea about getting tag number for that?
Looking for any delegate method does.

[image]

Comment: means you want to assign unique tag to every annotation?

Comment: Add code snippet where you adding annotation to MapView.

Comment: i don't want to assign. I already displaying annotations need to get index value for that if user clicking annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer this will return annotation tapped number:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
  NSUInteger index = [mapView.annotations indexOfObject:view.annotation];
  NSLog(@"index no %d",index);
}
```

The above code will generate random index number each time we tap on annotation.

**But need to rewrite code as below**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    // Annotation is your custom class that holds information about the annotation
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
        Annotation *annot = view.annotation;
        NSInteger index = [self.arrayOfAnnotations indexOfObject:annot];
    }
}
```